# Deleting rows in html using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 4 rows in my  HTML, which I want to delete dynamically. I am using jQuery for the same. But the issue is only 3 out of 4 rows get deleted. Here is the code:

```
function delverycdel(a) {
  var count = $("#count").val();
  //alert("Yunoos"+count);
  var hsncode22 = $("input[name='hsnper[]']").length;
  console.log("hsncode : " + hsncode22);
  /*if(count>1)
  {
    $("taxc"+a).remove();
    var elem = document.getElementById("taxc"+a); // getElementById requires the ID
          elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    var tc = parseInt(count)-1;
    $("#count").val(tc);
    SetDefault(a, "xyz");
          return false;
  }*/
  if (count > 1) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("taxc" + a);
    $("taxc" + a).remove(); // add remove here
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    var tc = parseInt(count) - 1;
    $("#count").val(tc);
    SetDefault(a, "xyz");
    return false;
  }
  //SetDefault(a, "YPA");
}
```

Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the HTML and also where you are calling the function to delete the table rows?

Comment: `$("taxc" + a).remove();` this is wrong, IDs must begin with a sharp: `$("#taxc" + a).remove();`

Comment: Thanks. It is now working correctly. @Ryosaku